# How to post data of checkbox by ajax Django?

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django, ajax

How can i submit the `is_read` checkbox field into database using ajax?
when i try to chick the checkbox field i am getting this error `core.models.Article.DoesNotExist: Article matching query does not exist.`

**models.py**

```
class Article(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    is_read = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

**views.py**

```
@csrf_exempt
def Story_status_update(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        pk = request.POST.get('pk')
        item = Article.objects.get(id=pk)
        print(item)
        item.is_read = True
        item.save()
        return JsonResponse({'succes': True}, status=200)
    else:
        return JsonResponse({'succes': False, 'errors': []}, status=400)
```

**Html**

```
<tbody>
    {% for object in articles %}
    <tr data-pk="{{ object.id }}">
        <td>{{ object.title }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="{{ object.id }}" name="is_read" id="id_is_read" /></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

**ajax.js**

```
    $("#id_is_read").click(function () {
        var pk = $('tr').attr("data-pk");
        $.ajax({
            type: "Post",
            contentType: "application/json;",
            url: "{% url 'status-update' %}",
            data: { pk: pk },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (response) {
                console.log(response)
            },
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure about the Django part but

For the Html, you are creating multiple checkboxes with the same id, which is invalid, use a class instead.

```
<tbody>
    {% for object in articles %}
    <tr data-pk="{{ object.id }}">
        <td>{{ object.title }}</td>
        <td><input type="checkbox" data-id="{{ object.id }}" name="is_read" class="class_is_read" /></td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}
</tbody>
```

And for the JavaScript use the class as the selector and select the correct row.
Also, the content type is wrong since you're not sending JSON so remove `contentType`

```
$(".class_is_read").click(function () {
    var pk = $(this).closest('tr').attr("data-pk"); // select the correct row
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "{% url 'status-update' %}",
        data: { pk: pk },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response) {
            console.log(response)
        },
    });
});
```